# Unable to configure CI build for Dot Net core 3.1 from deployment center. Is there any way to setup CI Azure DevOps

Tags: build, azure-devops, continuous-integration, devops, continuous-deployment

Unable to configure CI build for Dot Net core 3.1 from deployment center. 
Is there any way to setup CI Azure DevOps.
Please let us know is there any way to configure?.

Comment: Have you viewed this [blog](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SettingUpAzureDevOpsCICDForANETCore31WebAppHostedInAzureAppServiceForLinux.aspx) on setting up Azure DevOps CI/CD for a .NET Core 3.1 Web App.

Comment: @Prabu Sundaram Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to setup CI Azure DevOps

For this issue ,you can achieve this through the following tasks. The build pipeline performs various tasks such as fetching sources from the Git repository, restoring dependencies, compile the application, run tests and publishing outputs used for deployments.

[image]

Then selecting `Triggers`. The Azure DevOps project automatically created a CI trigger, and every commit to the repository initiates a new build. You can optionally choose to include or exclude branches from the CI process.

[image]

You can refer to this [lab](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azuredevopsprojectdotnet/#exercise-2-examine-the--cicd-pipelines-configured-by-azure-devops-project) for details. If you want to use yaml to set CI build, you can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops) and [guide](https://wakeupandcode.com/yaml-defined-cicd-for-asp-net-core/).